# Making both columns of a line as a dictionary key

Tags: python

I have two columns in a file which is in the format below:

```
00:01:02   aa:bb:cc  1
03:04:05   dd:ee:ff  2
```

and so on....

I want to make a key by combining first and second columns and make 3rd column as value. I am trying in this way. This is the only partial code:

```
 maindict = dict()
 lines = inf.readlines()
 ampdu = [x.split() for x in lines]
 ckey = '-'.join([ampdu[0],ampdu[1]])
 maindict[ckey] = ampdu[2]
```

I am facing an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'". Where am i doing wrong? I just posted a question few minutes back. Sorry this was so desperate to post so soon, but its kind of an urgency situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ampdu` is a list of lists, so when you use `join` you're trying to join the first and second lines of the file. Try iterating through that list to get each line individually.

```
for columns in ampdu:
```

Also you can use a tuple instead of a join to make a key.

```
ckey = (columns[0], columns[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ampdu` is a list of lists:

```
ampdu = [x.split() for x in lines]
```

so your `ampdu[0]` is actually the first line of your file, `ampdu[1]` your second, etc.

The reason why you're getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: list` is because dictionary requires their keys to be hashable [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Also, like [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) mentioned, you could use a tuple instead of joining them into a string and you can take advantage of unpacking to  shorten your code to something like this:

```
inf = open("foo.txt", "r")
maindict = {}

for line in inf:
    col1, col2, val = line.split()
    maindict[(col1, col2)] = val
```

Your dictionary will then look like:

```
>> print maindict
>> {('00:01:02', 'aa:bb:cc'): '1', 
    ('03:04:05', 'dd:ee:ff'): '2'}
```

And to access the values, you can use maindict[(col1, col2)]

```
>> maindict[('03:04:05', 'dd:ee:ff')]
   2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to take advantage of `operator.itemgetter` returning a tuple, and to build a generator over your file doing the `.split()` first, then a `dict-comp` over that, eg:

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_key = itemgetter(0, 1)
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    rows = (line.split() for line in fin)
    maindict = {get_key(row):row[2] for row in rows}
```

This also has the advantage that you can re-use `get_key` if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file') as f:
    lines = (line.split() for line in f)
    maindict = dict(('-'.join([line[0], line[1]]), line[2]) for line in lines)
```